# Error getCellStyle POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, cell

I'm trying to use the method getCellStyle of a Cell but I'm getting the exception. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OiJq.png)

Code:
getTemplate Object is XSSFWorkbook
Cell object is  org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

Cell cell = p_sheet.getTemplate().getSheetAt(0).getRow(v_i).cellIterator().next();

cell.getCellStyle();   <----

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Nitpicking: You are getting an exception rather than an error.

Comment: What type of object is p_sheet?

Comment: Hi, I put some informations in my post, do you have any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: We need more context about this. If `cell.getCellStyle()` produces `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException` then the `cell` is a `XSSFCell` but the `XML` of this cell is orphaned. That means the `XML` context of this cell (their row, sheet, workbook) has been lost. But maybe using a more actual version of `xmlbeans` jar may help. From your exception (code line 1213), you are using version `2.3.0` (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlbeans/tags/2.3.0/src/typeimpl/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/XmlObjectBase.java?view=markup#l1213). Current version is `2.6.0`.